# RestyGWT and Basic authentication

Tags: rest, gwt, spring-security, spring-boot, resty-gwt

After days without any progess, I need your help.

With GWT, I'm trying to communicate with my REST server, the server is on a different URL (CORS needed).
My configuration:
**Server**
- spring-boot 1.3.3

**Client**
- GWT 1.7
- restygwt 2.0.3

**Server side**, I think it's ok.
When I disable the security in Spring, I can get datas in my GWT client.
But when I enable it, I always get 401 requests. The REST URL request works directly in the web browser (with its authentication dialog).

**Client side**, I have followed this page:
 https://ronanquillevere.github.io/2014/04/11/restygwt-basic-auth.html

Here is my code:

The filter which adds credentials in the header

```
public class BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter implements DispatcherFilter {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
        try {

            String basicAuthHeaderValue = createBasicAuthHeader(
                    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.getUserName(),
                    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.getPassword());

            builder.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, basicAuthHeaderValue);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String createBasicAuthHeader(String userName, String password)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String credentials = userName + ":" + password;
        String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encode(credentials
                .getBytes()), "UTF-8");

        GWT.log("encodedCredentials=["+encodedCredentials+"]");

        return " Basic " + encodedCredentials;
    }
}
```

The dispacher:

```
public class MyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public MyDispatcher() {
        addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }

}
```

And my test call:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Defaults.setDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());

                UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setUserName("user");
                UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setPassword("psswd");

                String url = "http://localhost:8080/race";
                Resource resource = new Resource(url);

                resource.get().send(new JsonCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Method method, JSONValue response) {
                        GWT.log(response.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
                        GWT.log("Erreur: ", exception);
                    }
                });

            }
```

And now the resulting headers in web browser dev tools.

**Directly in the web browser:**
Request

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Authorization   Basic R3V5OnR5Y29vbg==
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
```

Answer

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 28 Apr 2016 17:35:31 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=A496281DBD6E9B797887B9C34B47DA52; Path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
x-content-type-options  nosniff
```

**GWT Client**
Request

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-He...    authorization,x-http-method-override
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8080
Origin  http://127.0.0.1:8888
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
```

Answer

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://127.0.0.1:8888
Allow   GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 28 Apr 2016 17:43:29 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=4D80D0C0FA9E27D166F6489CC88C3E45; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary    Origin
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="Realm"
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
access-control-allow-head...    authorization, x-http-method-override
access-control-allow-meth...    GET
x-content-type-options  nosniff
```

I have noticed 2 things:
- In the gwt header request, I do not have the Authorization value. However in the console log, I have a trace which confirm that my filter is triggered.
- Only with firefox, when I do my request, firebug catches 2 network paquets, the first has the Authorization value but no answer, the 2nd one is the results I decscribed above.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

My server rejects the pre-flight request submitted by the web browser.

I add a CorsFilter in my server, it's ignoring OPTIONS request

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse theResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest theRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        theResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", theRequest.getHeader("Origin"));

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(theRequest.getMethod())) {
            theResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            theResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            theResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-HTTP-Method-Override");
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```